# Sometimes We are getting following issue while running application on server

Tags: node.js, nodes

Error: read ECONNRESET

```
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } undefined
```

Comment: Maybe this can help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912439/nodejs-econnreset